# How can I insert the current date into my SQL Server table using a script in C#

Tags: sql-server

I have the following SQL:

```
public const string application =
@"SET IDENTITY_INSERT Application ON
INSERT INTO Application(ApplicationId, Name, ModifiedDate) VALUES (1, 'xx', );
INSERT INTO Application(ApplicationId, Name, ModifiedDate) VALUES (2, 'xx', );
INSERT INTO Application(ApplicationId, Name, ModifiedDate) VALUES (3, 'xx', );
SET IDENTITY_INSERT Application OFF
DBCC CHECKIDENT( 'Application', RESEED )";
```

I just added a ModifiedDate column to the table but as it's a NOT NULL then it requires me to change the SQL. Can someone explain to me how I can get the current date and insert it into my string. I understand there are different formats between the way C# and SQL handle the date. Do I need to convert to a different format? How about if I just wanted to use the date "January 1st, 2000", is there a particular format I would need to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to "create" the date in C# itself. SQL Server will process the query, so you can simply use getdate() in your sql. Or you can change the table adding default constraint to your column as getdate() and just skip it in sql.